# Mongo: how to find by ObjectId that is stored in a subarray?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find, objectid

I have a collection with records like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f01400027a"),
    "admins": 
       [ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f014000279"), ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f01400027e")]
}
```

I would like to search by the the 'admin' array.

How can I find all documents included for example ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f014000279") in the sub-array.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you delete [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941011/non-valid-json-with-escaped-commas-in-javascript)? The Solution is `JSON.parse( '{ "title_text": "\\\"s\\\"" }' )`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can match against array fields like `admins` the same as you would a non-array field:

```js
db.coll.find({admins: ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f014000279")})
```