# Is it possible to find a specific element in a subarray by ID and edit only that element?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515998/2891356) thinking it solved my problem until I realized that the query returns the whole parent document.

Is there anyway to query for, and edit only, a specific element in a subarray in a document?

So it'd go something like,

```
const newComment = {...};

const comment = await Post.find({comments: ObjectId("50ae3bdb50b3d6f014000279")})

comment.push(newComment);

await comment.save();
```

The reason I want to accomplish this is because comments are nested within the `Post` schema. It'd be more efficient if I can have the comment returned, specified with the comment ID, and cycle through all the likes of that comment. Instead of cycling through *all* the comments of the `Post`, and *then* cycling through all the likes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach ,

```
const newComment = {...};

Post.find( { "comments": "50ae3bdb50b3d6f014000279" } )
.exec((err , foundComment) => {
   if(err){
      console.log(err)
   }else{
     foundComment.push(newComment);
     foundComment.save();
   }

});
```